# Get Last NOT NULL values from all the columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a situation where I am trying to get last not null value from all the columns. here is some data to for demo puposes.

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT, Col1 INT, Col2 INT, Col3 INT, Dated DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1, NULL, 100  , NULL, '20131210'),  --<-- Column2 from this row
(1, 20  , 200  , NULL, '20131209'),  --<-- Column1 from this row
(1, 30  , NULL , 300 , '20131208'),  --<-- Column3 from this row
(1, 40  , 400  , NULL, '20131207')

╔════╦══════╦══════╦══════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ Col1 ║ Col2 ║ Col3 ║          Dated          ║
╠════╬══════╬══════╬══════╬═════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ NULL ║ 100  ║ NULL ║ 2013-12-10 00:00:00.000 ║
║  1 ║ 20   ║ 200  ║ NULL ║ 2013-12-09 00:00:00.000 ║
║  1 ║ 30   ║ NULL ║ 300  ║ 2013-12-08 00:00:00.000 ║
║  1 ║ 40   ║ 400  ║ NULL ║ 2013-12-07 00:00:00.000 ║
╚════╩══════╩══════╩══════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

I have built a query which returns the required results. But was wondering if there is a more performance efficient way of doing this. Since this way I am quering the whole table each time I hope to find a more efficient way of getting these results.

**My Query**

```
SELECT ColumnName, Col1 AS Value, Dated 
 FROM
(
SELECT TOP 1 'Column1' AS ColumnName
            , Col1 
            , Dated
FROM @t
WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY Dated DESC
)Q1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT TOP 1 'Column2' AS ColumnName
            , Col2 
            , Dated
FROM @t
WHERE Col2 IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY Dated DESC
)Q2

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT TOP 1 'Column3' AS ColumnName
            , Col3 
            , Dated
FROM @t
WHERE Col3 IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY Dated DESC
)Q3
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════════════╦═══════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ ColumnName ║ Value ║          Dated          ║
╠════════════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ Column1    ║    20 ║ 2013-12-09 00:00:00.000 ║
║ Column2    ║   100 ║ 2013-12-10 00:00:00.000 ║
║ Column3    ║   300 ║ 2013-12-08 00:00:00.000 ║
╚════════════╩═══════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

It returns the **correct results**. but I am sure it can be done with a bit **more simpler/efficient query**  . Any help or pointer is much appericiated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty much a straightforward [`UNPIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operation and an appropriate [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to select the most recent value. The `UNPIVOT` automatically eliminates `NULL` values:

```
;With Numbered as (
     select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col ORDER BY Dated desc) rn
     from @t
     unpivot (Value for Col in (Col1,Col2,Col3)) p
)
select * from Numbered where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
ID          Dated                   Value       Col      rn
----------- ----------------------- ----------- -------- --------------------
1           2013-12-09 00:00:00.000 20          Col1     1
1           2013-12-10 00:00:00.000 100         Col2     1
1           2013-12-08 00:00:00.000 300         Col3     1
```

Comment: You are a star Damien your query is the cheapest I have just compared all three solution, Mine 55%, Upendra's 28% and yours 17% of the batch. Cheers pal :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the in vertical row format your UNION option is better, but if you need it in horizontal column format then you can use self join like below

```
SELECT top 1 t1.Col1, t2.Col2, t3.col3
FROM @t t1
inner join @t t2 on t2.col2 is not null
inner join @t t3 on t3.col3 is not null
where t1.col1 is not null
order by t1.dated desc
```

Comment: Thank you for your reponse, much simpler and better solution then mine, it is pulling the right data but as you can see in my result set I am actually pivoting the results. would be kind enough to update to answer so I would get exactly the same results as shown in my desired output.