# Select last (recently) filled values from all columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table, say table with description as :

```
| ID | SNO |  c1   |  c2  |  c3   |
___________________________________
| 1  |  1  |  c11  | c21  |  c31  |
| 1  |  2  |  NULL | c22  |  c32  |
| 1  |  3  |  NULL | NULL |  c33  |
```

Now, what I need is:

```
|  c1   |  c2  |  c3   |
________________________
|  c11  |  c22 |  c33  |
```

It means: the last inserted value for each column for a particular reference, in this case, `ID = 1`.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042284/get-last-not-null-values-from-all-the-columns) link, the `WITH` clause, but unable to understand and use, also, due to MySQL 8.0 is not supported by the server.

Comment: you hav eonly 3 columns or the columns are much more ?

Comment: yes, more columns. But scenario is same with every column. I just want recent value from every column.

Comment: but you don't are looking for the last inserted  value,  but for the last inserted  not null ..

Comment: Yes. Last Inserted Column-wise. Which ever column is last inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like below to pick latest not null  value per group

```
select ID,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(c1 order by SNO desc),',',1) c1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(c2 order by SNO desc),',',1) c2,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_concat(c3 order by SNO desc),',',1) c3
from demo
group by ID
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2a7a5/5)

### Edit

To get the SNO also for each column your can update your query as below

```
select ID,
substring_index(group_concat(c1 order by SNO desc),',',1) c1,
substring_index(group_concat(case when c1 is not null then SNO end  order by SNO desc),',',1) sno1,
substring_index(group_concat(c2 order by SNO desc),',',1) c2,
substring_index(group_concat(case when c2 is not null then SNO end  order by SNO desc),',',1) sno2,
substring_index(group_concat(c3 order by SNO desc),',',1) c3,
substring_index(group_concat(case when c3 is not null then SNO end  order by SNO desc),',',1) sno3
from demo
where ID = 1
group by ID
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2a7a5/14)

Comment: I assumed "1" as ID in your example snippet. 
So, first, its giving all IDs.
Second, its giving comma separated values, starting from recent.
e.g.
ID -- C1 -- C2 -- C3
1 -- c11 -- c22,c21 -- c33,c32,31

Comment: then what is "1" at the end of `substring...` statements ??

Comment: You can add where clause to limit your records like `where ID = 1` after from clause http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2a7a5/6, Also where you can see comma separated list ? in demo fiddle you can see the exact same output as defined in your post, the "1" is to pick the latest value from colum

Comment: @VAThomas For more information have a look at documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Comment: yes yes, it worked. 
But when taking serialNumber from where the value is being taken it returns 1 only. For example, if correct value is returned, serialNumber is given as 1 only. Is it possible to get serialNumbers also for each column ?

Comment: @VAThomas for SNO i can give it a try but can you please ask a new question for this ?

Comment: Someone would mark it inappropriate. If you'd like I can update this question ? will it do ? Because I need to know from where the last value has been taken ? Need to save it in some other table for reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are various reasons why you might not want to use `substring_index()`/`group_concat()`.  I recommend using it with reservations:

- The values could have commas in them (then you might have to fiddle with separators).
- The internal buffer for `group_concat()` could overflow.
- You may not want to change the types of non-string values to strings.

An alternative is worth mentioning.  You can get the maximum `sno` for each column using an aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when c1 is not null then sno end) as c1_sno,
       max(case when c2 is not null then sno end) as c2_sno,
       max(case when c3 is not null then sno end) as c3_sno
from t
group by id;
```

Bringing in the actual values is just a matter of using `join`:

```
select id, t1.c1, c2.c2, t3.c3
from (select id,
             max(case when c1 is not null then sno end) as c1_sno,
             max(case when c2 is not null then sno end) as c2_sno,
             max(case when c3 is not null then sno end) as c3_sno
      from t
      group by id
     ) t left join
     t t1
     on t1.c1_sno = t.c1_sno left join
     t t2
     on t2.c2_sno = t.c2_sno left join
     t t3
     on t3.c3_sno = t.c3_sno;
```

If you want to filter this for particular `id`s, but the `where` in the subquery.

Comment: OK nice. I might, at a time, be receiving upto 500 results. So what would be the performance statistics ? Plus, an explanation would help to modify it as per my situation. Actually, there are two 't's and I am having confusion with the actual table name. Please modify your answer with table name as 'table1'. Thanks.